# Downloadable Elixir documentation

Tags: elixir

I have been searching [Elixir Web Site](http://elixir-lang.org/) for a downloadable archive of the Elixir documentation as html file but I could not find any.

So is the only solution to generate it from the sources or should I get myself a pair of glasses ?

Comment: Use Dash - https://kapeli.com/dash

Comment: @Vetal4eg dash looks great but it's an iOS app (unless I'm mistaken). I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Elixir v1.1.0 we include the docs as part of the releases: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases/tag/v1.2.0. Just scroll to the bottom of the page and you will find a link to download them.

I have also changed elixir-lang.org to offer links to the docs. The change should be up tomorrow when announce 1.2 on the site.

Answer (score 4):

```
wget https://github.com/elixir-lang/docs/archive/gh-pages.zip
unzip gh-pages.zip
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/elixir-lang/docs.git
```

Answer (score 3):

For linux you can use [Zeal](https://zealdocs.org/) (Dash for linux)